# Chosen.jquery.js incompatible jquery-1.9.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Estou usando o Jquery-.1.9.1 na minha aplicação e gostaria de usar o componente chosen.jquery.js contudo esse componente usa o 1.6.4. Eu quero usar esse componente dentro das dialog que é aberta pelo jquery 1.9.1. 
Tentei usar o noConflict contudo não funcionou.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
});
```

```html
z<html>
<body>
    <head>
        <title>Add a title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/chosen.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <select class="chosen-select" tabindex="8" multiple style="width:350px;" data-placeholder="Your Favorite Types of Bear">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option>American Black Bear</option>
            <option>Asiatic Black Bear</option>
            <option>Brown Bear</option>
            <option>Giant Panda</option>
            <option selected>Sloth Bear</option>
            <option disabled>Sun Bear</option>
            <option>Polar Bear</option>
            <option disabled>Spectacled Bear</option>
        </select>
      


        <script src="~/Content/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
        
        <script>
               
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: cara o chosen suporta 1.4 pra cima olha la no git jQuery support: 1.4+
testei aqui com essa versão de jquery q vc disse q funciono de boa. tem certesa que o problema da incompatibilidade é este?

Comment: @JasarOrion pra min não funciona. Acontece esse erro
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).chosen is not a function

Comment: choosen funcionando com js 1.9.1 https://jsfiddle.net/v4cwv9qg/

Comment: eu acho q vc não deve usar ~ no caminho dos seus arquivos.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está relacionado ao jquery ui dialong que não funciona com o chonsen.jquery.

https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/646